# Java Code : How do I select files from a directory based on their date modified which should be equal to the date specified in the string

Tags: java, string, file, date, last-modified

I have a date value in string "03/09/16".How do I select files from a directory based on their date modified which should be equal to the date specified in the string.

My requirement is to select only files which have their "date modified"="date specified in the string".

Comment: File systems are OS dependent, are you ok with a solution that only works with one OS?

Answer (score 0):

For your case:

```
File file = new File("C:\\Temp\\filenmae.type");
Date modifiedDate = new Date(file.lastModified());
Calendar modifiedCal = Calendar.getInstance();
modifiedCal.setTime(modifiedDate);
Calendar cal = (Calendar) modifiedCal.clone();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 2); // Start from 0
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 9);      
if (modifiedCal.compareTo(cal) == 0) {
    System.out.println("Same date!!!"); 
}
```